# How to Retrieve list of members chat room in using XMPP framework?

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

How can I retrieve the list of members of a chat room in using XMPP framework?

I tried using:

```
 - (void)xmppRoom:(XMPPRoom *)sender didFetchMembersList:(NSArray *)items
```

But it returns an empty array. Any one please help me?

Answer (score 2):

when you joined the room delegate xmpproom delegate will call so after that return following code.

```
-(void)xmppRoomDidJoin:(XMPPRoom *)sender
{

    DDLogInfo(@"joined room");
    [sender fetchMembersList];
}
```

after that it calls  following delegate method.

```
-(void)xmppRoom:(XMPPRoom *)sender didFetchMembersList:(NSArray *)items
```