# fetch group list along with buddy list in xmpp ios

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I am implementing xep-0045 for group chat functionality in my iphone app. I can get buddy list from XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject model, from where I can get list of group I created or joined?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19004006/how-to-retrieve-list-of-members-chat-room-in-using-xmpp-framework